# Where and how can I view skype logs (Chat and Voice history)?

Tags: skype, history

Where and how can I view my skype logs (Chat and Voice history)? Does it get saved somewhere in PC by default? Can I choose a folder location myself to start saving voice and chat history?

Answer (score 20):

> how can i view skype logs?

There are plenty of third-party tools for that: [Skyperious](https://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/), [SkypeBrowser](http://www.skypebrowser.com/), any SQLite browser & many others

> Does it get saved somewhere?

Yes, that's the (incomplete) list of possible locations from SkypeBrowser website:

*On Windows 7, 8, 10:*

```
C:\Users\<WindowsUserName>\AppData\Roaming\Skype\<SkypeUserName>\main.db
```

*On Windows XP:*

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<WindowsUserName>\Application Data\Skype\<SkypeUserName>\main.db
```

*On Mac OS:*

```
~/Library/Application Support/Skype/<SkypeUserName>/main.db
```

*On Linux:*

```
~/.Skype/<SkypeUserName>/main.db
```

*Also on Windows 10:* (updated 2019-05-07)

```
%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_*\LocalState\<SkypeUserName>\skype.db
```

> Can i choose a folder location myself to start saving voice and chat
>   history?

I don't know any way to do this

Answer (score 10):

As of April 2017 and the new Skype for Windows 10 (Skype UWP - Universal Windows Platform), the `main.db` file has moved to

```
%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\LocalState\<SkypeUsername>\skype.db
```

with `%localappdata%` being `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local`

Source: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_win10-skype_startms/skype-app-data-folder-missing-directs-me-to/e4ecb6ca-f64d-4983-b768-727237638fb2

Answer (score 8):

Skype profile data (including contacts, chat & voice history, etc...) is saved in `%AppData%\Skype\<skype username>` which will typically be `c:\Users\<windows username>\AppData\Roaming\Skype\<skype username>` on a Windows Vista/7/8 system.

The databases are in SQLite3 format and will require an SQLite viewer to properly view them.

I'm not aware of any user-friendly way to change the location of Skype profile data, but it can be redirected to any location using symbolic links (for advanced users only).

Answer (score 3):

Normally it will be stored at `main.db file` for windows operating system

the default path for Windows XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<windows user>\Application Data\Skype\<WindowsUsername>
```

the default path for Windows 7+:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Skype\live#<SkypeLiveUsername>
```

1. Close Skype
2. Navigate to run command
3. type `%appdata%\skype`
4. Navigate to your user name (skype username)
5. you could find all the info at main.db file

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

There is a neat tool [SkypeLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/skype_log_view.html). It is old but works like charm.

Comment: Seem it's not fully functional cause on my machine it don't load messages after 09.01.2018 (9th January 2018)

Answer (score 3):

It used to be possible to export your message history from a database file on your PC using various tools, but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore. You can't access the chat history on your PC in a recent version of the app but you can download it from Skype Online.

1. Go to [Skype's data export tool](https://secure.skype.com/en/data-export) and sign in with the proper account.
2. Select "*Conversations*" and click "*Submit request*".

   [image: Skype's data export tool]
3. Wait for the export to complete. This can take a while depending on the amount of logs you have.
4. When the export is complete, download it. It will be available for 30 days.

   [image: An available export]
5. The data will be downloaded in a `.tar` archive. Use a software such as [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to extract the contents. You might see "Unexpected end of data". That's normal.

   [image: 7-zip's extraction results]
6. Open the `messages.json` file with a decent JSON viewer. I've found browsers are generally good for this.