# Unable to find Skype chat history on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, skype, chat

I'm using Skype (not for Business) on Windows 10. I want to export my chat logs to a text file. I read [Where and how can i view skype logs (Chat and Voice history)?](https://superuser.com/questions/634587)
and other posts which say I should look in `%appadata%\Skype`.

But all this folder contains is `RootTools\roottools.conf`. There is no user folder in there. Where are my chat logs?

Comment: Did you also see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1267648/650163) within that previous question?  If you don't have the desktop version of Skype (and are utilizing the UWP version, instead), that answer should help you.