# Skype Message History - How to quickly access messages from years ago?

Tags: skype

I'm on Windows 10, using:
Skype version 8.61.0.100
Application version 15.61.100.0

I need to access messages from few years ago, but using the search option doesn't get any matches since it's probably not cached anymore, and trying to scroll up all the time is terrible, I've been doing it for 10 minutes and only got to messages that are not old enough.

Can't see any export option either. however, the history is saved, I just can't scroll and scroll all the time, it's too hard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where and how can i view skype logs (Chat and Voice history)?](https://superuser.com/questions/634587/where-and-how-can-i-view-skype-logs-chat-and-voice-history)

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/634587/911683), so I've moved [my answer there](https://superuser.com/a/1573056/911683). The portion that is unique to this question is:

Searching the `messages.json` file can be a bit of a pain. The conversations are grouped by the contact you were talking to and sorted by the date the message was sent in reverse chronological order. It also includes calls in this list.

I'm not currently aware of any tools to make it easier to search.